# How to define the length of a Text in SWT depending on the text to display?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a Text which will display different data of different length. Initially I was using a Textbox of fixed length. But, obviously It was not working.
Then, I tried to get the length of the text, using that length as a width of the Text , like this -

```
textName = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
String myText = tree.getSelection()[0].getText();
int length = myText.length();
textName.setBounds(76, 28, length, 21);
textName.setText(myText);
```

But, I found that the length of a string and the width of the Text field in SWT, are quite different.
So, is there any solution for this purpose? Obviously, I can set a higher value to the width.. But, I think, that will not be a good solution.

Comment: Why don't you create a util function which trims the string based on width ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, I need to display the whole text , flexibly increasing or decreasing the size of the textbox. I am sorry, if I have conveyed it wrong.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using absolute sizing of widgets? What if the full width of the `Text` will be wider than the width of its parent?

Comment: Using [Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) rather than setBounds lets the layout do all the sizing for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the `Text` object calculate its default size.
First set the text, then call `computeSize` which computes the screen pixel size of the text string:

```
Text textName = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
String myText = tree.getSelection()[0].getText();
textName.setText(myText);
Point size = textName.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
textName.setBounds(76, 28, size.x, 21);
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot!. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute string size with current font size and type by:

```
GC gc = new GC(textName);
Point textSize = gc.textExtent(myText);
gc.dispose();
```

textSize gives you size of Your text in pixels. Then you could determine size of Text control to set.